# Get-ADUSER related issue

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I was building this script to compare the **samaccountname** with the **homefolder name in the homedirectory attribute (the last in the path)**  & if they r not same - then just rename the homefolder and update the homedirectory attribute.

It would be something like this I suppose -

```
Get-aduser -filter * | foreach {

$_.samaccountname
```

dont know how to capture homedirectory and then cut it to get what i want..

so help pls!

Answer (score 0):

The following should work

```
$users = (Get-ADUser -filter * -properties "HomeDirectory")
foreach ($user in $users)
{
    $HomeFolder = "UNCFolderPath" + $user.SamAccountName
    if ($user.homedirectory -notmatch $user.SamAccountname)
    {
        Set-ADUser $user.SamAccountName -HomeDirectory $HomeFolder
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: This will hit all AD accounts so I would maybe work on a smaller sample of users to start with if this is production, maybe use a -Searchbase on Get-ADUser and narrow the filter down instead of using a wildcard.

Comment: what is  "UNCFolderPath" ?

Comment: It could be anything like \\servername\home\users\.... The root folder on the server that the home folder is located before the username. So in your instance it would be \\10.20.30.40\HOME\